# How to create the db file for Room prepopulation

Tags: android, android-room

I am very new to Android development and Room.
I have followed the [documents](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/prepopulate) and I know I can prepopulate the Room database using  `.createFromAsset("database/myapp.db")`

However, how could I create the `myapp.db` in the first place? Do I need to re-write the table schema in SQL and use some SQL tools to create the file first?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, use Python or DB related free tools to execute your relevant queries & add data into them then push that db in to the app's asset directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, how could I create the myapp.db in the first place?
> Do I need to re-write the table schema in SQL and use some SQL tools to create the file first?

Creating the database is not difficult use any third party tool, adding the entities (tables, indexes etc) is quite simple as Room generates the code.

You can get the SQL for the EXPECTED schema simply by

1. making the project (CTRL + F9 in Android Studio) and
2. then looking in the **Android** View,
3. then expand the **App**  and there will be a java(generated) directory/folder, 1. in the @Database's file, the SQL for the respective creation of the tables exists.

- 'See below for a pictorial guide of the above'

For example a project consists of an @Database as per :-

```
@Database(entities = {EmailEntity.class, ContactEntity.class}, version = 3)
//@TypeConverters({DateConverter.class, TimeConverter.class})
public abstract class EmailsDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    private static EmailsDatabase instance;

    public abstract EmailsDao emailsDao();
    public abstract ContactsDao contactsDao();
    //public abstract HeaderDao headerDao();

    public static synchronized EmailsDatabase getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                    EmailsDatabase.class, "emails_database")
                    .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                    .build();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

As can be seen there are 2 tables/entities EmailEntity and ContactEntity they are :-

```
@Entity(tableName = "emails_table")
public class EmailEntity {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "email_from")
    private String emailFrom;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "email_to")
    private String emailTo;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "email_subject")
    private String emailSubject;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "email_body")
    private String emailBody;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "email_date")
    private String dateReceived;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "email_time")
    private String timeReceived;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "email_filename")
    private String filename;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "email_archive")
    private Boolean isArchived;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "email_token")
    private String emailToken;

    .... (code for constructors/getters/setters removed for brevity)
}
```

and

```
@Entity(tableName = "contacts_table")
public class ContactEntity {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "email_token")
    private String emailToken;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "email_to")
    private String emailTo;

    private String password;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "contact_name")
    private String contactName;

    .... (code for constructors/getters/setters removed for brevity)
}
```

After Making the project in the Android view expanded as explained above, you see (selections highlighted) :-

[image]

In **`EmailsDatabase_Impl`** you see/get :-

```
@SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "deprecation"})
public final class EmailsDatabase_Impl extends EmailsDatabase {
  private volatile EmailsDao _emailsDao;

  private volatile ContactsDao _contactsDao;

  @Override
  protected SupportSQLiteOpenHelper createOpenHelper(DatabaseConfiguration configuration) {
    final SupportSQLiteOpenHelper.Callback _openCallback = new RoomOpenHelper(configuration, new RoomOpenHelper.Delegate(3) {
      @Override
      public void createAllTables(SupportSQLiteDatabase _db) {
        _db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `emails_table` (`id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, `email_from` TEXT, `email_to` TEXT, `email_subject` TEXT, `email_body` TEXT, `email_date` TEXT, `email_time` TEXT, `email_filename` TEXT, `email_archive` INTEGER, `email_token` TEXT)");
        _db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `contacts_table` (`id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, `email_token` TEXT, `email_to` TEXT, `password` TEXT, `contact_name` TEXT)");
        _db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS room_master_table (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,identity_hash TEXT)");
        _db.execSQL("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO room_master_table (id,identity_hash) VALUES(42, '2f17fa6d4f6206a3879b74b27b022576')");
      }

      @Override
      public void dropAllTables(SupportSQLiteDatabase _db) {
        _db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `emails_table`");
        _db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `contacts_table`");
        if (mCallbacks != null) {
          for (int _i = 0, _size = mCallbacks.size(); _i < _size; _i++) {
            mCallbacks.get(_i).onDestructiveMigration(_db);
          }
        }
      }
    .... (code omitted for brevity)
```

Simply copy and run the SQL in the third part tool. Save and you have the database. Obviously populating the tables may be more laborious.
You would not use the SQL for room_master_table.